# C --> malloc --> dlsym

Tags: c, malloc, dlsym

I have used `dlsym()` to invoke my version of malloc, instead of the default library malloc:

```
 lt_malloc = (void*(*)(size_t))dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "malloc");
 TRACE((stderr, "initialize: lt_malloc=%p\n", lt_malloc));
 if (!lt_malloc) {
     fprintf(stderr, "LeakTracer: could not resolve 'malloc' in 'libc.so': %s\n", dlerror());
     exit(1);
 }
```

Now after certain time, may be a timer or so, i want to revert back to the original version of malloc (libc library malloc). How can i do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Does the above code mean 
1) you have called your malloc also malloc?
2) or that you assign the libc malloc to lt_malloc?

The code above suggests that lt_malloc is the libc malloc so the "original" malloc. Well you than probably have some either some macros or a function

So then you switch as easily as
   my_malloc = libc_malloc
   my_malloc = my_debug_malloc

and you just call my_malloc

If  that is not  helpful please explain the posted code and what you expect at "ente codde here"

Comment: @Friedrich: Please refer the man page for dlsym, especially the use of macro RTLD_NEXT. Yes, we have our own malloc code somewhere, in the program which will be called.

Comment: I know what dlsym does and so lt_malloc is the libc malloc. So where's your malloc  then? What's is name and how to you call it via a Macro or another functon pointer or how?

Comment: No, i think in that case, you need to know better about macro RTLD_NEXT. I will copy-paste here an excrept from man page: `There are two special pseudo-handles, RTLD_DEFAULT and RTLD_NEXT. The former will find the first occurrence of the desired symbol using the default library search order. The latter will find the next occurrence of a function in the search order after the current library. This allows one to provide a wrapper around a function in another shared library.`

Comment: The answer i guess is RTLD_DEFAULT, but what happens if my version of malloc is already loaded in memory? Does RTLD_DEFAULT overwrite it?

Comment: Your malloc surely is not in libc.So where is it?

Comment: @Friedrich: I have a malloc defined in my file, which i haven't put here. lt_malloc will point to the original libc malloc

Comment: I'm quite aware that lt_malloc is the "libc" malloc. And therefor I asked what's thename of your malloc? Is it  also malloc or not?

Comment: @Friedrich: Ofcourse it will be "malloc", otherwise do you think we can put the wrapper?

Comment: @Friedrich: If we carefully study the man page sometimes, hit and trial is not required. But anyways as you asked me, let me tell you: RTLD_DEFAULT will always hit my malloc, and will go to an infinite loop. (It's tested)

Answer (score 0):

You should rather use dlopen on the library containing your malloc function and use the handle from dlopen as a first argument to dlsym.

Alternatively, you can [use LD_PRELOAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083337/overriding-malloc-using-the-ld-preload-mechanism).