# LD_PRELOADing malloc and free

Tags: c, linux, gcc, ld-preload

I wrote my own *malloc* and *free* and compiled them in a shared library. I LD_PRELOAD that library with my program. In this way would my program always use my custom *malloc* and *free* or are there cases where it is not so. I've heard that gcc has built in malloc and *free* too. Is it possible that the glibc that came with my gcc is using the builtin *malloc* and *free*.

Secondly, I notice that when I run my program, I'm seeing the *free* function call more often than the *malloc/calloc* calls (98 to 16). I don't do any memory allocation myself (except in one place), so all allocation is being done by standard library functions that I use. And also note I'm using pthread in my program. If you want to know, my program looks like this.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define NUM_THREADS     8

pthread_mutex_t m = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

int sum;
float total = 1;
extern int __did_libc_start_main;

void *PrintHello(void *threadid)
{
   long tid;
   tid = (long)threadid;
   pthread_mutex_lock( &m );
   sum++;
   total *= total + tid * 0.097891313423578;
   printf( "p%d, tid%d, total = %g, start = %d!\n", getpid(), tid, total, 0 );
   pthread_mutex_unlock( &m );
   printf("Hello World! It's me, thread #%ld!\n", tid);
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
   int rc;
   long t;
   char * p;
   char * m;

   fork();

   p = (char*)mmap(0, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
   p[0] = 78;
   printf( "p = %p, p[0] = %d, pid = %d!\n", p, p[0], getpid() );
   m = (char*)malloc( 80 );
   printf( "m = %p!\n", m );
#if 1  
   for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++)
   {
      printf("In main: creating thread %ld\n", t);
      rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, PrintHello, (void *)t);
      if (rc){
         printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
         exit(-1);
      }
   }
   for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++)
    pthread_join(threads[t], NULL);

   printf( "\n\nTotal = %g\n\n", total );

   /* Last thing that main() should do */
   pthread_exit(NULL);
#endif
   printf( "\n\n%d: Done without major problems\n\n", getpid() );
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Near-duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083337/overriding-malloc-using-the-ld-preload-mechanism

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `LD_PRELOAD` to override `malloc` etc. is expected to work; this is how e.g. [DUMA](http://duma.sourceforge.net/) works.

In addition to `malloc`, `calloc` and `free`, make sure you override `realloc`, `memalign` and `valloc`.  In addition you might need to override C++ `new`, `new[]`, `delete` and `delete[]`.

See [Overriding 'malloc' using the LD_PRELOAD mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083337/overriding-malloc-using-the-ld-preload-mechanism) for an example of how to do this right.

Comment: finnw: `strdup` calls `malloc`