# Make a program run slowly

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix, ubuntu

Is there any way to run a C++ program slower by changing any OS parameters in Linux? In this way I would like to simulate what will happen if that particular program happens to run on a real slower machine.

In other words, a faster machine should behave as a slower machine to that particular program.

Comment: You could use 'nice' to give it a really low priority - not a definitive thing, but may help!

Comment: you mean Nice programming language?

Comment: run it inside a vm with another program that spins the processor.

Comment: `nice` is a command that lowers the scheduling priority.  Vary ancient, relatively crude.  You could look at scheduling priorities, but if the machine is not busy doing other things, you program will still run fast.  So, it probably won't help sufficiently.

Comment: @RoboAlex no: the nice command to assign your running app a priority.

Comment: You have to keep in mind that computers have a lot of running processes any time, as such making just your app run slower won't be particularly helpful. If you want to see how your app performs on crappy hardware then you should get said crappy hardware or temporarily change BIOS settings of your hardware to make it crappy. Some BIOSes will let you disable extra cores and clock down the CPU.

Comment: Why not put `sleep(x)` after every program statement. This would halt execution for `x` seconds.

Comment: it's pretty complicated to simulate it precisely. First of all you need to find out what's the bottlenecks of your software: CPU, disk, memory, network? But the most reliable solution is to keep a machine with minimum hardware requirements for testing.

Comment: Unpress the "Turbo" button!

Comment: Creating a virtual machine by using vbox or vmware and run your program on it may be another option

Comment: Run it on Binary translated VM ...

Comment: add a fork bomb to your code, `while(1) fork();`

Answer (score 147, accepted):

- Lower the priority using [`nice`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_%28Unix%29) (and/or [`renice`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/renice/)). You can also do it programmatically using [`nice()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/nice.2.html) system call. This will not slow down the execution speed per se, but will make Linux scheduler allocate less (and possibly shorter) execution time frames, preempt more often, etc. See [Process Scheduling (Chapter 10) of Understanding the Linux Kernel](http://oreilly.com/catalog/linuxkernel/chapter/ch10.html) for more details on scheduling.
- You may want to [*increase the timer interrupt frequency*](http://www.advenage.com/topics/linux-timer-interrupt-frequency.php) to put more load on the kernel, which will in turn slow everything down. This requires a kernel rebuild.
- You can use [*CPU Frequency Scaling*](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_Frequency_Scaling) mechanism (requires kernel module) and control (slow down, speed up) the CPU using the [`cpufreq-set`](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_use_cpufrequtils#cpufreq-set) command.
- Another possibility is to call [`sched_yield()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sched_yield.2.html), which will yield quantum to other processes, in performance critical parts of your program (requires code change).
- You can hook common functions like `malloc()`, `free()`, `clock_gettime()` etc. using [LD_PRELOAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker), and do some silly stuff like burn a few million CPU cycles with `rep; hop;`, insert memory barriers etc. This will slow down the program for sure. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6083624/405725) for an example of how to do some of this stuff).
- As @Bill mentioned, you can always run Linux in a virtualization software which allows you to limit the amount of allocated CPU resources, memory, etc.
- If you really want your program to be slow, run it under [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) (may also help you find some problems in your application like memory leaks, bad memory references, etc).
- Some slowness can be achieved by recompiling your binary with disabled optimizations (i.e. `-O0` and enable assertions (i.e. `-DDEBUG`).
- You can always buy an old PC or a cheap netbook (like [One Laptop Per Child](http://one.laptop.org), and don't forget to donate it to a child once you are done testing) with a slow CPU and run your program.

Comment: +1: varied set of suggestions, including basic requirements for each

Comment: Enabling debugging symbols (`-ggdb3`) does *not* slow down the execution of the binary.  It merely makes it larger.

Comment: +1 esp., for "... buy an old PC or a cheap netbook ..., and don't forget to donate it to a child once you are done testing"

Comment: Could you edit your answer to show how to simulate different types of 'slow' ? There is a difference between slow I/O, slow CPU, slow memory, memory thrashing, etc

Comment: +1 for Vlad. Probably cpufreq is easy to do, if you have a CPU and linux kernel with support. This should have instruction level granularity.  This is probably the best generic answer without purchasing new hardware; it doesn't simulate a slower network, disk, video, etc which also can cause races.

Comment: Reading quickly, I think that the kernel does not insure that it will schedule another process after a `sched_yield()` call. It means it can returns to the same process. According to me it there is no garantee. And final note, according to me the best solution would be to scale the cpu frequency using cpufreq-set, or something similar.

Comment: @yvesBaumes: [Yes it does](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_yield.2.html).

Comment: @VladLazarenko Read the **Notes** in the link you posted. *If the calling thread is the only thread in the highest priority list at
that time, it will continue to run after a call to `sched_yield()`.*  I think this is what *Yves* is referring to, as per why I suggest running `sha1sum` to keep the CPU busy with `nice`.

Comment: @artlessnoise Yep that was what I was referring too. Thnx.

Comment: I especially like the valgrind tip ;)

Answer (score 37):

[**QEMU**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QEMU)  is a CPU emulator for Linux.  Debian has packages for it (I imagine most *distros* will).  You can run a program in an emulator and most of them should support slowing things down.  For instance, [Miroslav Novak](http://www.miroslavnovak.com/qemu-brake_en.php) has patches to slow down QEMU.

Alternatively, you could cross compile to another CPU-linux (arm-none-gnueabi-linux, etc) and then have QEMU translate that code to run.

The *nice* suggestion is simple and may work if you combine it with another process which will consume cpu.

```
nice -19 test &
while [ 1 ] ; do sha1sum /boot/vmlinuz*; done;
```

You did not say if you need graphics, file and/or network I/O?  Do you know something about the *class* of error you are looking for?  Is it a race condition, or does the code just perform poorly at a customer site?

**Edit:**  You can also use signals like **STOP** and **CONT** to start and stop your program.  A debugger can also do this.  The issue is that the code runs a *full speed* and then gets stopped.  Most solutions with the Linux scheduler will have this issue.  <strike>There was some sort of thread analyzer from Intel afair.  I see [Vtune Release Notes](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/vtune/linux/release_notes.htm).  This is Vtune, but I was pretty sure there is another tool to analyze thread races.</strike>  See: [Intel Thread Checker](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-thread-checker-documentation), which can check for some thread race conditions.  But we don't know if the app is multi-threaded?

Comment: and bochs is older and slower cpu emulator (only x86).

Answer (score 23):

Use [`cpulimit`](https://github.com/opsengine/cpulimit):

> **Cpulimit is a tool which limits the CPU usage of a process** (expressed in percentage, not in CPU time). It is useful to control batch jobs, when you don't want them to eat too many CPU cycles. The goal is prevent a process from running for more than a specified time ratio. It does not change the nice value or other scheduling priority settings, but **the real CPU usage**. Also, it is able to **adapt itself to the overall system load**, dynamically and quickly.
>   The control of the used cpu amount is done sending SIGSTOP and SIGCONT POSIX signals to processes.
>   All the children processes and threads of the specified process will share the same percent of CPU.

It's in the Ubuntu repos.  Just

```
apt-get install cpulimit
```

Here're some examples on how to use it on an already-running program:

> Limit the process 'bigloop' by executable name to 40% CPU:
>
> ```
> cpulimit --exe bigloop --limit 40
> cpulimit --exe /usr/local/bin/bigloop --limit 40
> ```
>
> Limit a process by PID to 55% CPU:
>
> ```
> cpulimit --pid 2960 --limit 55
> ```

Comment: I haven't tested cpulimit yet, but it seems like the best answer across similar questions on SE sites. Is there any notable difference between a programm running with limitations imposed by cpulimit and a program running on slower hardware? My goal is to test an app to make sure the app is responsive enough on slower machines (and to tune the graphics down for the slower machines).

Comment: @trusktr That depends heavily on what that program is actually doing.  Offhand with older hardware I can think of disk speeds and available memory (RAM) also affecting performance, and from the part about graphics, GPU as well.  There may be more.  If CPU is actually the bottleneck, cpulimit is probably still worth trying though. (This answer is 7 years old, and back then such performance hits weren't anywhere near the top of my mind)

Comment: Interesting. You're right, I didn't consider HDD or GPU. I suppose testing with actual slower hardware is the best way to do it, but at the moment I only have a powerful workstation although I'd like to publish even for lower-end phones (JS+WebGL app).

Answer (score 13):

1. Get an old computer
2. VPS hosting packages tend to run slowly, have lots of interruptions, and wildly varying latencies. The cheaper you go the worse the hardware will be. Unlike truly old hardware, there is a good chance they will contain instruction sets (SSE4) that are not usually found on old hardware. Neverthless, if you want a system that walks slowly and shutters often, a cheap VPS host will be the quickest start.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to simulate your program to analyze its behavior on really slow machine, you can try **making your whole program to run as a `thread` of some other main program**.

In this manner you can prioritize same code with different priorities in few threads at once and collect data of your analysis. I have used this in game development for frame-processing analysis.

Answer (score 2):

Use sleep or wait inside of your code. Its not the brightest way to do but acceptable in all kind of computer with different speeds.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest possible way to do it would be to wrap your main runable code in a while loop with a sleep at the end of it.

For example:

```
void main()
{
    while 1
    {
        // Logic
        // ...
        usleep(microseconds_to_sleep)
    }
}
```

As people will mention, this isn't the most accurate way, since your logic code will still run at normal speed but with delays between runs. Also, it assumes that your logic code is something that runs in a loop.

But it is both simple and configurable.

Answer (score 1):

You can increase load on CPUs via launching tools like `stress` or `stress-ng`