# Monitor memory requests of running process

Tags: c++, c, debugging, memory, profiling

I have a slow-running process that uses some poorly-documented libraries.

I suspect the libraries are killing performance by continuously copying lots memory (in RAM). This hypothesis is support by the fact that `perf record/report` tells me that `memcpy` is using 15% of my time.

But I'd like to catch this red-handed, as it were. I believe I could detect this condition if I could get a sense of the amount of memory per time unit that the program is trying to allocate.

Is there are a tool such as `gdb` or `prof` which I can use to attach to a **running process** and get a sense of its malloc/free statistics?

Comment: `valgrind` should give you stats on how much memory was allocated.

Comment: Malloc and free are defined as weak symbols, so you can replace them with with custom versions that provide tracing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17803456/an-alternative-for-the-deprecated-malloc-hook-functionality-of-glibc

Comment: Just another question where double-tagging wrecks the question. In C++, you can replace `operator new`. If you're dealing with C, theoretically you can't replace `malloc`. (But in practice, you might).

Comment: And `valgrind` in `callgrind` or `cachegrind` mode can also give exact information of function call stacks (chains - which functions called memcpy) with some information like "profiling" (with in-order 1-cycle cost model of every instruction, unlike real out-of-order cpu model)

Comment: @MSalters: Just so. Though perhaps double-tagging is more appropriate in this instance: the C++ code is interfacing with libraries written in C.

Comment: @Richard: Important information. So important in fact that it should be in the question.