# Applications for detecting memory leaks

Tags: c++, ubuntu, memory-leaks, g++

I am seeking for an application that could help me detect memory leaks in my C++ program. I am compiling using g++ over Ubuntu.

Is there such an application found on **Ubuntu repository** other than **Valgrind** cause it is not working for my case.

Comment: What do you mean with "it is not working". As far as I know it works quite fine with Ubuntu.

Comment: Suspect XY problem.  If Valgrind does not run, it's not unlikely that other memory diagnostic tools would also fail.  Fix Valgrind.

Comment: Something like this case: http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.crashes

Comment: @MartinJames, I expect that you are right. I just want to make sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this wikipage looks useful for you:

[Memory_debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_debugger)

I never use this kind of program before, and I have Windows, so i don't know which is good, but maybe you found one.

Comment: Ok I will check them, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

four detecting memory leaks under linux you can use valgrind.

[look at this link it contains some examples](http://www.cprogramming.com/debugging/valgrind.html)

Instead of valgrind you can use addresssanitizer.

Comment: Thank you dear, but I already mentioned that Valgrind didn't work for my case.

Comment: oh sorry! did you try addresssanitizer

Comment: Not yet, I will try it now

Answer (score 1):

There are so many options.

But a typical one for linux systems would be [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). It is a dynamic memory analyzer.

It is very easy to use. The basic idea is that you call valgrind and let it fork the application to be debugged. Valgrind replaces standard library calls with some own wrappers, which allows it to track memory allocations and deallocations. If the application cancels you get an summary about your memory consumption and detailed listing about memory leaks.

Maybe you should note that a complex application could take some time to start up inside the memory debugger and could also run very slowly.

Comment: Thank you dear, but I already mentioned that Valgrind didn't work for my case

Answer (score 0):

Use ld_preload. Something like this:

https://github.com/jrfonseca/memtrail

Comment: Thank you dear, but I already mentioned that I want an application that is found in Ubuntu repository.

Comment: @Mohamad-jaafar It is included in the default Ubuntu packages.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't find it even in searching apt-cache

Comment: I can't find any package for it, so doing it yourself is very easy. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18455795/308421