# blocking call to `dlsym` (RTLD_NEXT)

Tags: c, macos, macos-mojave, dlsym

I am trying to wrap function. To do that I thought about using `dlsym` to get the real function location in memory after having injected my dynamic library.

I am running on `MacOS Mojave (10.14.6)` with `Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.8)`.

I tried to run a rather simple code displaying a message each time `malloc` was called.

So I used the code of this post : [Overriding 'malloc' using the LD_PRELOAD mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083337/overriding-malloc-using-the-ld-preload-mechanism)

My test code was :

```cpp
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    (void)malloc(1);
    (void)malloc(1);
    return (0);
}
```

I injected the dynamic library using `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=./mylib.so DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE=1` on OSX and `LD_PRELOAD=./mylib.so` on Ubuntu.

On OSX, the program is blocking on the `dlsym` call where as on a Ubuntu docker box, the program works fine.

EDIT:

As @R.. pointed out, the `dlsym` implementation on OSX is calling malloc (see sources : https://opensource.apple.com/source/cctools/cctools-667.8.0/libdyld/dlopen.c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that calling `dlsym` causes a recursive call to `malloc`, which in turn causes a recursive call to `dlsym`, which deadlocks the second time because it already holds some lock. Using preload libraries to *wrap* `malloc`, rather than fully replacing it, is generally a bad idea, for this and other reasons.

You might be able to use `LD_AUDIT` or the equivalent functionality on OSX (if any) to print a trace of when `malloc` is called. Otherwise you could drop in a full replacement malloc with debug output.

Comment: Could be, because this method works fine for the `open` function

Comment: @GrandChaman: Because `dlsym` doesn't call `open`. Of course `dlsym` calling `malloc` is really bad design because it means `dlsym` can spuriously fail with out-of-memory conditions, but that's the kind of bad quality of implementation I'd expect from Apple's libc...

Comment: Note that `fprintf()` can also call `malloc()`, so there's another path to infinite recursion.

Answer (score 1):

You may also be falling into infinite recursion due to calling `fprintf()`, so using this code to interpose on `malloc()` is dangerous (copied from the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083337/overriding-malloc-using-the-ld-preload-mechanism)):

```
void *malloc(size_t size)
{
    void *p = NULL;
    fprintf(stderr, "malloc(%d) = ", size);
    p = real_malloc(size);
    fprintf(stderr, "%p\n", p);
    return p;
}
```

Library code such as `fprintf()` is likely to call `malloc()`.

Comment: I tried removing them, didn't work either. I narrowed down the problem to the `dlsym` call itself (using `write` for debugging)