# How to initialize/define a memory region and let multiple malloc (in glibc) allocates memory from this region?

Tags: c, linux, memory, malloc, glibc

I want to initialize a memory region and thus can use `malloc` (in glibc) to allocate memory only from this region. There will be multiple `malloc` used and every `malloc` operation should only use this pre-defined region. This region requires contiguous memory addresses with a specific size.

My thought is to create a `region_init` function that uses `sbrk` or shared memory object (using `shm_open`?) to initialize a memory region that can be used by (multiple) `malloc`. BTW, I think `mmap()` doesn't work for this scenario because `mmap()` doesn't always return contiguous addresses. The problem is that I don't know how to make every `malloc` use this memory region I created (using `sbrk`? shared memory? and/or others?). Can I achieve this by modifying the source codes of `malloc` in `glibc`? If I can, how to modify glibc (any idea is appreciated)? What should I do for implementing this functionality?

Before this question, I asked a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62824113/how-to-modify-the-malloc-behavior-in-glibc-and-test-if-it-works-as-expected) on StackOverflow. In the previous question, some answer/comment suggested that I can use a single malloc to allocate a large memory buffer/region and implement my own API to manage this memory (e.g., `m_malloc` to allocate part of the memory from this memory buffer/region). However, the problem of this design is that it is hard to `free` especially when there are multiple variables in this region. The `free` in glibc can only free the whole region that is malloc'd. If I want to free a variable (when there are many variables in this malloc'd region), I can only free the whole region which means all of the variables are freed. I really want to use `free` to free the memory of any variable I allocated in the memory region created by only one `malloc`.

I hope my question is clear. Thanks for your help and ideas.

Comment: If you allocate memory out of a buffer you manage yourself, you wouldn't call `free` to release the memory.  You'd call e.g. `m_free` which would free the memory in your internal buffer so it can potentially be returned by a later call to `m_malloc`.  You need to keep track of what regions of memory are available and which ones are not.

Comment: Thanks. If so, I must manage the memory using a structure like doubly-linked list? I should manage the free blocks with some method like Best fit and First fit by myself, but how should free the variable in the intermediate space of memory region? using a bit 0/1 to indicate this block is free or not. Is there any efficient way to manage large memory region? Thanks again!

Comment: You can always look at how glic does it and implement something similar.

Comment: Thank you. Do I need to modify the source code of `malloc` and `free` in glibc? or I just need to implement a wrapper that directly uses unmodified `malloc` and `free`?

Comment: You don't want to modify glibc as that will affect all processes on the system.  Instead just use that code as a basis for your own.  Use the built-in `malloc` to get a large block of memory, then you write `m_malloc` to allocate memory out of that pool and `m_free` to give memory back to that pool.  How exactly you do that depends entirely on your specific requirements.