Custom `malloc()` with CPython
How can I attach a custom malloc() to python? The docs allow you to switch the "malloc() function of the C library", presumably libc etc.
I want to link some other malloc() suite.

It seems like you could set PYTHONMALLOC=malloc to get it to dynamically link to malloc, then use LD_PRELOAD to redirect the malloc call to a library of your choice. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083337/overriding-malloc-using-the-ld-preload-mechanism That would avoid recompiling python.
